# How can I configure Emacs to use XeLaTeX without AUCTeX

Tags: xetex, emacs

The title says it all I hope, I'd like to configure Emacs to use XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX, which is the default. I'm using MiKTeX on Windows (it's in my PATH), if that makes a difference.

I'm pretty sure there must be a simple way to achieve this, but I'm by no means an Emacs expert.

Comment: Why on earth do you refuse to use AUCTeX?

Comment: I have a couple of reasons. First, because it's not available everywhere; Second, every time I wish to upgrade Emacs I have to go through [this long page](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download-for-windows.html) to make sure I didn't mess up anything. Third, I just don't see the value added.. Lastly, why should I accept to use AUCTeX? :-)

Comment: Use xemacs, that one comes with AUCTeX integrated ;-)

Comment: Lots of reasons not to use AUCTeX, but principally a) it's mainly for mathematicians, so it's full of good stuff I simply don't need; b) it changes the key-bindings.

Comment: Difficulty of installation is no longer an issue for AUCTeX, as it is now easily available from ELPA or EmacsMirror.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a piece of cake, as it should be! :

`(setq latex-run-command "xelatex")`

Answer (score 0):

You can run shell commands like `pdflatex` or `biber` on files in the various file manager modes. Dired is the most widely used one. There's also a number Midnight Commander clones.

See: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryDirectories.

But I still think you should give AUCTeX a second chance. If the versions available for Windows or Mac are not up to date (I have no idea), you might be better off running a Linux VM or setting up a Linux system on another partition. Although Emacs package management is getting much, much better, Linux package management still makes life with Emacs easier.